# Fetching directories from another repository in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a CI/CD pipeline which is triggered when there are any changes to repository A. I am trying to fetch and build a directory from a repository B within this pipeline. I am not sure how to do it. Any inputs will help. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into git submodules?

Comment: yes. I am not able to checkout git submodule in VSTS build definition...

Comment: yes, you can checkout submodules in a VSTS build definition. Under Get Sources, enable advanced settings and check the box.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, with git submodule, you need to checkout submodules in build:

1. Edit build definition
2. Select **Get sources**
3. Check **Checkout submodules option**

Secondly, you can clone other repository programming to the working directory during the build, for example:

1. Edit build definition
2. (Option) If the repositories are in different projects: Select **Options** tab, select **Project collection** in **Build job authorization scope**
3. Select **Tasks** tab, select the **Phase**
4. Check **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option
5. Add Command line task (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `clone https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@xxx.visualstudio.com/_git/xxx`; Working folder: xxx)

Comment: Sorry..was away for a couple of days..yes I was able to solve this issue by following the above mentioned steps..thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should have two builds, one for Repo A, and one for whatever you need in Repo B.  In your Build Pipeline, add artifacts from both of these builds to your pipeline, you are not restricted to just one artifact/pipeline.